# service accounts in windows server 2016

Tags: windows, server, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2016

i got a windows service running for an application in windows server 2016 server.
lets say "abcd " service.

service runs good. but if i restart the server = service fails to start and when i press start manually it says password incorrect.
if i stop and start the service manually = same , it says password incorrect.

but the password is correct. if i enter the password manually and start it works good.

is there any cache i need to clear out for service accounts ?? or why it keeps saying password incorrect and not starting automatically after restart..
if i enter same password manually it works good

Comment: This sounds more like a server issue than a programming one.

Comment: ya i know.. and it happens only for 1*windows service..
rest all works fine.  

so i was wondering whether is there any cashe credentails where i need to clear up and update passwords ?

Comment: well, the only suggestion is to check the service's login credentials in the services' properties when you run services.msc

Comment: ya checked it.  entered correct password many times.. but still when i stop/start - it does not start ...    ... always has to enter password to start it :(